# graph monthly exchange rate

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib, finance

I took the data from this website https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/H10/hist/dat96_ja.txt

I want to make a line graph showing the average monthly rate in 1997 and 1998.

So the x-axis will be Jan 97, Feb 97, ....., Dec 98.

This is what I have done until now

```
import pandas as pd
usyen = pd.read_csv("usyen.csv")
usyen = usyen.iloc[6:]
usyen[['Date','Rate']] = usyen.Column1.str.split(expand=True)
usyen.reset_index(inplace=True)
usyen = usyen.drop(['Column1', 'Column2', 'index'], axis=1)
usyen

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style = 'whitegrid')
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize = (10,5))

x = usyen(usyen.Date == 1997, 1998)['Date']
y = usyen['Rate']

ax.plot(x,y)

ax.set_title('Yen/US Exchange Rate')
ax.set_xlabel('Year')
ax.set_ylabel('Rate')
```

My problem is that the graph doesn't show up.
Error: 'DataFrame' object is not callable

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

About your error:

```
x = usyen(usyen.Date == 1997, 1998)['Date']
```

To filter your dataframe, you should use `[...]` and not `(...)`. To fix your code use:

```
m = usyen['Date'].str.contains(r'-(97|98)$')  # ends with -97 or -98
x = usyen.loc[m, 'Date']
y = usyen.loc[m, 'Rate']
```

However, you can optimize your code:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

sns.set(style = 'whitegrid')

# Read data
url = 'https://www.federalreserve.gov/releases/H10/hist/dat96_ja.txt'
hdr = {'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:109.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/112.0'}
df = pd.read_csv(url, skiprows=6, header=None, na_values='ND', names=['Date', 'Rate'], sep='\s+', engine='python', storage_options=hdr)
df['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Date'], format='%d-%b-%y')

# Extract subset and plot
df1 = df[df['Date'].between('1997-01-01', '1998-12-31', inclusive='left')]
ax = df1.plot(x='Date', y='Rate', title='Yen/US Exchange Rate', legend=False)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]